# MyModelAdmin must have search_fields for the autocomplete_view

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

I have 404 in Admin suggest with error

```
ApartmentPromotionAdmin must have search_fields for the autocomplete_view.
```

My admin organized as follows

```
from string import Template

from dal import autocomplete
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AutocompleteSelect
from django.forms import widgets



class ApartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ApartmentForm
    list_display = ("id", "address", "apartment_number", "owner")
    search_fields = ["id", "address"]
    autocomplete_fields = ["owner"]

class PromotionApartmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            "apartment":
            AutocompleteSelect(
                ApartmentPromotion._meta.get_field("apartment").remote_field,
                admin.site,
                attrs={"style": "width: 400px"},  # You can put any width you want.
            ),
        }


class ApartmentPromotionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PromotionApartmentForm
    list_display = ("id", "apartment")
    autocomplete_fields = ["apartment"]
```

I have

```
admin.site.register(ApartmentPromotion, ApartmentPromotionAdmin)
```

and models are

```
class ApartmentPromotion(models.Model):
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="promotions")
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return f"<{self.id}> {self.apartment} {self.status}"

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=["id"]),
            models.Index(fields=["apartment_id"]),
        ]
class Apartment(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="owned_apartments")
    ....

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=["owner_id"]),
        ]
```

could you help me to fix the problem ?

p.s.
connected with
`'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'get_limit_choices_to'` error

Comment: The error message looks very clear: you have autocomplete_fields but no search_fields... did you try to add some? To be honest it's just a supposition coming from the message itself ;-)

Comment: thanks, i thied with (obviously) incorrect add of serch_filelds and got new error 
'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'get_limit_choices_to' googling of with leadme to the solution

Comment: I would have been surprised you did not, but just in case... ;-) It's good you found the solution

Answer (score 1):

I have find solution here https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32619

> Problem solved. Cause was traced down to an evolution of the
>
> ```
> BaseModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey method:
> if db_field.name in self.get_autocomplete_fields(request):
>     kwargs['widget'] = AutocompleteSelect(db_field.remote_field, self.admin_site, using=db)
> ```
>
> became
>
> ```
> if db_field.name in self.get_autocomplete_fields(request):
>     kwargs['widget'] = AutocompleteSelect(db_field, self.admin_site, using=db)
> ```

In my case i should change

```
ApartmentPromotion._meta.get_field("apartment").remote_field,
```

to

```
ApartmentPromotion._meta.get_field("apartment"),
```